# Application Insight does not send data without using Thread.Sleep

Tags: azure, telemetry, azure-application-insights

I have a console application that runs through a web job scheduler after 15 minutes interval. But problem is that Application Insight Telemetry does not send data without using Thread.Sleep at the end of the code.

```
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
         Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility.TelemetryConfiguration.Active.InstrumentationKey = "APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY";
        //do others stuff
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10000);
   }
```

Here, I am using 10 sec for thread sleep. But sometimes it misses some data of the last portion. But, after giving 70 sec it working fine.

I want to know, what is the minimum sleep time where every data will be sent.

Or, there is any other way which does not need Thread.Sleep.

Comment: Are you doing any async or threaded calls inside of //do other stuff? If they're running in a different thread they're going to be terminated when the main console thread ends

Comment: No there is no async call

Comment: Without seeing a bit more of the code involved it's going to be hard to comment

Comment: @Peter Bons is correct. This should be made the answer and accepted.

Answer (score 1):

What happens if you set DeveloperMode to true as outlined [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-api-custom-events-metrics#debug)? AI does not send telemetry items directly. If it does work in developer mode maybe you should call Flush as outlined [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-api-custom-events-metrics#flushing-data). Also, bear in mind it can take a few minutes before items appear in the portal